# Can't press the button in UITableViewCell after iOS 15 update

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView that rapidly update the data and there is a button in the UITableViewCell. From iOS 11 to 14, it works perfectly but after the iOS15 update, the button is broken.

- It seems to be untouchable while the cell is updating. So, I can't touch the button
- It need to touch on it a lot of times to make the button action fired
- When it fired, some time is fire as another cell context. For example: I press the button on cell 1 it should send the sender from cell 1 to the responder but it send the sender from cell 2 instead

The button was embedded as

```swift
   cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.doSomething(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Anyone has some suggestion for me? Thank you

**UPDATE**
I found the solution is use reconfigure instead of reloadData for UITableView

```swift
    let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!
    if !indexPaths.isEmpty {
        tableView.reconfigureRows(at: indexPaths)
    }
```

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without any details how the button is embedded in the UITableViewCell, and how the touch event is being handled.

Comment: Also, check typos and grammatical errors.  Sine iOS 11?  Are you talking about trigonometry?

Answer (score 0):

cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Remove this line in your code.